# How to convert SpatVector column to datetime format in R?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct, terra

I would like to convert a SpatVector column from character to POSIXct in R. Using `as.POSIXct()` doesn't throw an error or warning but the column is still character after.

```
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)

v$DateTime <- "2022-03-02 01:23:45"
class(v) # class = character

v$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(v$DateTime)
class(v) # class = character

class(as.POSIXct(v$DateTime)) # class = POSIXct
```

Comment: SpatVector does not yet support date/time values. I will add that soon.

Comment: @RobertHijmans any updates on when date/time support will be added?

Comment: It has been added already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available in terra >= 1.7-39

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.39
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v$DateTime <- "2022-03-02 01:23:45"
class(v$DateTime) 
#[1] "character"

v$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(v$DateTime)
class(v$DateTime) 
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Answer (score 0):

As Robert mentioned, there is no support in `terra` yet. Below solution with `sf` package:

```r
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
library(sf)

v <- st_read(f)
v$DateTime <- as.POSIXct("2022-03-02 01:23:45")

class(v$DateTime)
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>